# Heat pipe performance degrading

Tags: heat, heatsink

Compact electronics such as notebook computers often rely on active cooling with heat pipes. Looking into a Fujitsu Lifebook right now that has its cooler running on "all engines full ahead" even at close to zero CPU load I was wondering what could be wrong with cooling before replacing the cooling unit. Dust is not an issue and the heat transfer paste has been replaced currently - not that it changed much.

So my question would be: **Is there any plausible and reasonably probable failure or degradation mechanism of heat pipes that would go unnoticed?**

Comment: what about evaporation

Comment: That's the question. Could one expect the fluid to evaporate from a sealed system or is it conceivable to have small leaks to have it gone slowly. If yes how to verify that this is the issue.

Comment: Of course its possible, it is called "leak"

Comment: Check for damage on the ends of the heatpipe. If you can give us pictures, that might help diagnose physical damage as the reason for loss of internal fluid.

Comment: Consider also a failure in the fan speed control loop such that it can no longer sense light thermal loads. Can you place a thermocouple at the CPU end of the heatpipe? Or is there temperature monitoring in the BIOS settings? If the CPU is actually staying cool, the heatpipe may be fine and the fan is spinning needlessly.

Comment: I have read that they can degrade if non-condensable gasses build up inside (from diffusion or contamination). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pipe

Comment: @user2943160, I can't find any observable leaks (though the cold end is mounted in a fashion that makes it impossible to be sure). However I'd think that a complete loss of fluid would increase the systems effective thermal conductivity beyond a point where any useful operation of the notebook becomes possible.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I was thinking something like that could be an issue too. There are conditions with the fan spinning at lower rpm so the loop can't be completely disfunctional. I'll have to get a thermocouple though, measurement seems worthwhile.

Comment: When your laptop is blowing full-steam, is it also producing a lot of heat? If so, your CPU is not actually idling.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of heat pipe is to TRANSFER heat from hot place (CPU) to cold place (heat exchanger/fins). To remove the heat from "cold end", the end still must maintain some significant delta over ambient air. First indication that a heat pipe has lost its functionality would be if the CPU end is overheated (as measured either by internal sensor, or by touch of a thermocouple), while the cooled end is at room temperature.

And yes, the pipes are factory sealed to maintain low pressure, and quality of seal/weld can deteriorate over time.

Answer (score 0):

yea heat pipes can be a serious problem. My old but wonderful Toshiba laptop has had serious heat problems. Seems the BIOS no longer RELYABLY turns on the 2 fans when they are needed. Sometimes they run fine, sometimes they are running too slow for the heat, and sometimes they wont run at all. One processor has burned out and I got a cheap replacement on Ebay. So I wired tiny switches to the fans so I can run them as I please. But I noticed the heat pipe doesnt work "sometimes". It must get vapor lock or something. Its not the paste because sometimes the CPU side of the heat pipe is really hot and the fan side cool. Other times it carries the heat away just fine. But always, if the laptop is turned on its end, that heat pipe dont work no more and the temperature soars. Its old so i figured the old heatpipes on Ebay could be just as iffy. So now I run these fans all the time and dont leave it on unattended. Im thinkin the fluid over the years and the soaring temperatures has made part of the fluid leach out.

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend *paragraphs*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, heatpipes can fail. The result is that the CPU is very hot, but the other end of the heatpipe is cold. I saw one desktop CPU cooler that failed in this way. CPU is ~80C, while the radiator is cold even with the fan stopped.